# triggers and contains not working on sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I have a database with employee and department tables I want to make a trigger or constraint to prevent adding a employee with higher salary and the manager of the department they work for.
my tables look like this:
employee: Fname, Lname, ssn, Super_ssn, Bdate, Dno(reference for dnumber in department)) , Salary
department: Dnumber, Dname, mgr_ssn(reference to super_ssn in employee) mgr_start_date.

```
ALTER TABLE
    EMPLOYEE
ADD
 CONSTRAINT SALARY_CONSTRAINT CHECK(
 NOT EXISTS (
 SELECT
 *
 FROM
                EMPLOYEE E,
                EMPLOYEE M,
                DEPARTMENT D
 WHERE
                E.Salary > M.Salary
 AND E.Dno = D.Dnumber
 AND D.Mgr_ssn = M.Ssn
        )
    );
```

I tried the following code for the constraint but it says nested queries are not allowed in constrains

and tried the following code for the triggers its not showing any error but also not working.

```
CREATE TRIGGER SALARY_VIOLATION BEFORE
INSERT
 ON EMPLOYEE BEGIN
SELECT
    RAISE(
        FAIL,
 "employee salary cannot be more than the manager salary"
    )
FROM
FROM
    EMPLOYEE E,
    EMPLOYEE M,
    DEPARTMENT D
WHERE
    E.Salary > M.Salary
 AND E.Dno = D.Dnumber
 AND D.Mgr_ssn = M.Ssn
END;
```

any help will be  appreciated.

Comment: You mention `sqlite`, an RDBMS platform, in your title; however, in your question tags you have `mysql`, a completely different RDBMS. Please change the tags/title to match whichever platform you are using.

Comment: "contains" seems to be a typo for "constraint"

Comment: You have two `FROM` in the query, is that a copying error? You should also learn to use ANSI JOIN instead of cross products.